# Why do some character literals cause Syntax Errors in Java?

Tags: c#, java, unicode, syntax-error

In the latest edition of JavaSpecialists newsletter, the author mentions a piece of code that is un-compilable in Java

```
public class A1 {
  Character aChar = '\u000d';
}
```

Try compile it, and you will get an error, such as:

```
A1.java:2: illegal line end in character literal
              Character aChar = '\u000d';
                                ^
```

Why an equivalent piece of c# code does not show such a problem?

```
public class CharacterFixture
{
  char aChar = '\u000d';
}
```

Am I missing anything?

EDIT: My original intention of question was how c# compiler got unicode file parsing correct (if so) and why java should still stick with the incorrect(if so) parsing?
EDIT: Also i want myoriginal question title to be restored? Why such a heavy editing and i strongly suspect that it heavily modified my intentions.

Comment: Haha. You except Java to change? I needed that laugh :)

Comment: You can restore your original title (click on the "edited X time ago" link to see the revisions). However, the original title was subjective and argumentative to compare Java's "way" and C#'s "way". They are different languages with different specifications.

Comment: @pst - but with this title , I should not have asked the question as the same newsletter gives enough explanation. I respect the edits and am not forcing to restore it. My intention was why the difference in this context between two similar compilers.

Comment: I did not mean to lose than intent (and I think it still exists, even if not at the forefront). At this point, the only explanation I can give is "because this is how the specifications are written". While not always the case, *I* find that C# generally "cleaned up" the syntax used by Java while progressively adding new features not found in Java .. I suspect that some of these basic parse "warts" were addressed by the individuals working back on C# 1.0 (which postdates Java by at least several years and was heavily influenced by Java).

Answer (score 12):

Java's compiler translates `\uxxxx` escape sequences as one of the very first steps, even before the tokenizer gets a crack at the code.  By the time it actually starts tokenizing, there are no `\uxxxx` sequences anymore; they're already turned into the chars they represent, so to the compiler your Java example looks the same as if you'd actually *typed* a carriage return in there somehow.  It does this in order to provide a way to use Unicode within the source, regardless of the source file's encoding.  Even ASCII text can still fully represent Unicode chars if necessary (at the cost of readability), and since it's done so early, you can have them almost anywhere in the code.  (You could say `\u0063\u006c\u0061\u0073\u0073\u0020\u0053\u0074\u0075\u0066\u0066\u0020\u007b\u007d`, and the compiler would read it as `class Stuff {}`, if you wanted to be annoying or torture yourself.)

C# doesn't do that.  `\uxxxx` is translated later, with the rest of the program, and is only valid in certain types of tokens (namely, identifiers and string/char literals).  This means it can't be used in certain places where it can be used in Java.  `cl\u0061ss` is not a keyword, for example.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "later", "certain types of tokens", "certain places"?

Comment: @Vic: "Later" is about as clear as i can make it, and "certain places" even came with an example.  I've added clarification for "certain types of tokens".